# Python-Sockets: Evaluation using IF statement behaves erroneously

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, client-server, tcp, python-sockets

## Node.py

```
import socket
import sys
import time
import pp_json as ppjs
import SWATT as sw

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#Get Client IP
client_IP = sock.getsockname()

#Status message for node
status_message = {'Node ID' : 'NS-1', 'Status' : 'Online', 'Node IP' : client_IP }

#Message serialized
ser_clientMsg = ppjs.pp_json(status_message)

#Start Verification variable initialization
flag = '101'


# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
server_address = ('localhost', 10100)
print >>sys.stderr, 'connecting to Verifier at %s port %s' % server_address
sock.connect(server_address)


var=1
try:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'Sending Node Status "%s"' % ser_clientMsg
    sock.sendall(ser_clientMsg)
    # Send data
    while var:
        recvData = sock.recv(256)
        print >>sys.stderr, 'Received from Verifier: "%s" \n' % recvData
    if recvData == flag:
        print "Starting verification process...\n"
        filename = "hello.txt"
        fh = open(filename,"r")
        temp_str = fh.read()
        checksum = sw.SWATT(temp_str, len(temp_str))
        sock.sendall(checksum)
finally:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'closing socket'
    sock.close()
```

## Verifier.py

```
import socket
import sys
import time as t
import json

startTime = t.time()

#Count variable initialization
count = 0

#Send Start Verification Prompt
start_verif = '101'

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 10100)
print >>sys.stderr, 'Starting Verifier on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)

#Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    #Wait for connection
    print >>sys.stderr, 'Waiting for connection establishment'
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'Connection from', client_address

        #Receive the data in chunks and retransmit it
        while True:
            if count == 0:
                statusData = connection.recv(256)
                parsedData = json.loads(statusData)
        #print >>sys.stderr, 'Received "%s"' % parsedData
                print "Received Node Status: \n", json.dumps(parsedData, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
                count+=1
            elif count == 1:
                print 'Sending Verification Trigger:\n', start_verif
                connection.sendall(start_verif)
                count+=1
                checksum = connection.recv(256)
                print "Checksum value from Prover: ", checksum
                print "\n"
            else:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'SWATT successfully computed on Node with Node address: ', client_address

    finally:
        elapsedTime = t.time() - startTime
        print elapsedTime
        connection.close()
```

I guess the problem is at Line 37 in Node.py as I am able to see the value 101 printed of previous line that is Line 36 on Node terminal. Can you help me find exactly where is the error. Also, please comment if you require the codes of the modules which I have imported. I will be happy to post them subsequently.

Answer (score 0):

```
while var:
    recvData = sock.recv(256)
    print >>sys.stderr, 'Received from Verifier: "%s" \n' % recvData
if recvData == flag:
```

When you have received the data, you have not decoded the data before checking it for the flag. Try before the if statement: `recvData = recvData.decode('utf-8')`

I don't really use python 2 but from what I can tell, this should work.